# How can I programmatically get the Terminal scrollback text?

Tags: terminal

I ran across [this comment](https://superuser.com/a/304224/110370) which stated that it is possible to access the text in the macOS Terminal scrollback:

> Finding text in scrollback is a weakness of most terminal emulators; the only ones I know of that provide it are OS X Terminal and [Terminator](https://code.google.com/p/jessies/).

I've done some searching, but I have not had any luck finding anything online saying how this can be done.

The reason I ask is that I'm looking for possible solutions to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66862219/how-can-i-automate-opening-a-gradle-failed-test-report-in-my-web-browser-on-dema), and am investigating whether there is a way to get text from the most recently run command in the macOS Terminal.

For this specific use case, I'm hoping to find the line(s) that match a particular pattern, so I can extract the matching text and pass it to the `open` command.

```
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///path/to/parent-project/child-project-1/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
```

↓

```shell
open file:///path/to/parent-project/child-project-1/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
```

In short, how can I get the text of the Terminal scrollback?  Bonus points if it's limited to just the ouptut of the last command, but I can make a workable solution to my problem if I can get the entire Terminal scrollback text.

Comment: Do you want to search (like in a Text Editor) or extract?

Comment: I'm specifically hoping to get the text of a line that matches a particular pattern.  I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Pointing out that really, you're solving the wrong problem. This application should be logging its "test" results to a file, not outputting them to the screen to disappear.  Does the application really only output its results to the screen?

Comment: @MarcWilson No, it logs them to a file.  It's the location of the file I'm trying to scrape.  The file location varies based on which project I'm in, or which subproject(s) failed validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is only one instance of the `file:///.../index.html` **URL** in the contents of the entire scrolling buffer of the tab, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* can do that:

```
tell application "Terminal" to ¬
    set tabHistory to ¬
        history of tab of ¬
        front window as text

set fileURL to ¬
    do shell script ¬
        "grep -o 'file:///.*\\.html' <<< " & ¬
        tabHistory's quoted form & "; exit 0"

if fileURL is not "" then ¬
    do shell script ¬
        "open " & fileURL's quoted form
```

---

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above acts on the selected tab of the front *window* in **Terminal**.

If there is a `file:///.../index.html` **URL** in the contents of the entire scrolling buffer it will be opened by the `open` *command*.

If there is more than one instance of the `file:///.../index.html` **URL** in the contents of the entire scrolling buffer of the tab, then make the following change in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* above to open the last instance of the `file:///.../index.html` **URL**:

**Change**:

```
set fileURL to ¬
    do shell script ¬
        "grep -o 'file:///.*\\.html' <<< " & ¬
        tabHistory's quoted form & "; exit 0"
```

**To**:

```
set fileURL to ¬
    last paragraph of ¬
    (do shell script ¬
        "grep -o 'file:///.*\\.html' <<< " & ¬
        tabHistory's quoted form & "; exit 0")
```

If you want to use **Safari** to open the **URL** and have it frontmost, then:

**Change:**

```
if fileURL is not "" then ¬
    do shell script ¬
        "open " & fileURL's quoted form
```

**To:**

```
if fileURL is not "" then ¬
    tell application "Safari"
        make new document with properties {URL:fileURL}
        activate
    end tell
```

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be saved as a *shell script* with a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang*, made *executable* and run from **Terminal**.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Confirmed that this solution works as advertised.  I'll probably play around with it a bit later when I have the chance.  Thanks!

Comment: Since we're in AppleScript land anyway, I've replaced `do shell script "open " & fileURL's quoted form` with `tell application "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL:fileURL}`, as that opens the URL in a new window, rather than as a tab in my frontmost window.  (As an aside, I'm not very strong at AppleScript. Do you know if there's a way to bring focus to this new window I'm creating this way, without bringing the entire Safari application to the forefront?)

Comment: @M. Justin, See the update under "If you want to use Safari to open the URL and have it frontmost, then:" in the **Notes** section of my answer.

Comment: This is the solution I've been using, and has been working well for my purpose.  Thanks!